# Find connected pixel points of multiple contours

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, contour

I have an image segmentation output in which I got different objects having separate boundaries.
i.e. I can have multiple contour over an image.
I want to write an algorithm which will trace all the contour and give output in the form of connected pixel points for each contour.
Is there any previously defined algorithm for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the binary image processing library

https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/binaryimagelibrary

It's quite a hunk of code

```
#define CNT_TOPLEFT 0x80
#define CNT_TOPRIGHT 0x40
#define CNT_BOTTOMRIGHT 0x20
#define CNT_BOTTOMLEFT 0x10

#define CNT_RIGHT 1
#define CNT_DOWN 2
#define CNT_LEFT 3
#define CNT_UP 4

static int walkcontour(unsigned char *binary, int width, int height, int x, int y, int dir, double **cx,
                        double **cy, int *Nret);


/**
   Go round a binary image, extracting the contours of the set pixels.

   @param[in]    binary - the image
   @param width - image width
   @param height - image height
   @param[out] x -  return for x co-ordinates of contours (malloced)
   @param[out] y -  return for y co-ordinates of contours (malloced)
   @param[out] Nret - return for contour lengths (malloced)
   @returns Number contours found, -1 on out of memory.
 */
int getcontours(unsigned char *binary, int width, int height, double ***x, double ***y, int **Nret)
{
    int xi, yi;
    int i;
    unsigned char neighbours[9];
    int N;
    double *cx, *cy;
    int cN;
    void *temp;
    double **contourx = 0;
    double **contoury = 0;
    int *contourN = 0;
    int err;
    int answer = 0;
    int capacity = 0;

    for(yi=0;yi<height;yi++)
    {
        for(xi=0;xi<width;xi++)
        {
            if(binary[yi*width + xi] & 0x01)
            {
                get2x2(neighbours, binary, width, height, xi, yi, 0);
                N = 0;
                for(i=0;i<4;i++)
                    N += neighbours[i] & 0x01;
                if(N != 4)
                {
                    if( (binary[yi*width+xi] & CNT_TOPLEFT) == 0 &&
                       (neighbours[0] & neighbours[1] & neighbours[3] &0x01) == 0)
                    {
                       err =  walkcontour(binary, width, height, xi, yi, CNT_RIGHT, &cx, &cy, &cN);
                       if(err == 0)
                       {
                           if(answer >= capacity)
                           {
                               capacity = capacity + capacity/2 + 10;
                               temp = realloc(contourN, capacity * sizeof(int));
                               contourN = temp;
                                temp = realloc(contourx, capacity * sizeof(double *));
                               contourx = temp;
                               temp = realloc(contoury, capacity * sizeof(double *));
                               contoury = temp;
                           }
                           contourN[answer] = cN;
                           contourx[answer] = cx;
                           contoury[answer] = cy;
                           answer++;
                       }
                    }
                    /*
                    if( (binary[yi*width+xi] & CNT_TOPRIGHT) == 0 &&
                       (neighbours[1] & neighbours[2] & neighbours[5] &0x01) == 0)
                    {
                        walkcontour(binary, width, height, xi +1, yi, CNT_DOWN, &cx, &cy, &cN);

                    }
                    if( (binary[yi*width+xi] & CNT_BOTTOMRIGHT) == 0 &&
                       (neighbours[5] & neighbours[7] & neighbours[8] &0x01) == 0)
                    {
                        walkcontour(binary, width, height, xi, yi+1, CNT_LEFT, &cx, &cy, &cN);

                    }
                    if( (binary[yi*width+xi] & CNT_BOTTOMLEFT) == 0)
                    {
                        if( (binary[yi*width+xi] & CNT_BOTTOMRIGHT) == 0 &&
                           (neighbours[5] & neighbours[7] & neighbours[8] &0x01) == 0)
                        walkcontour(binary, width, height, xi+1, yi+1, CNT_UP, &cx, &cy, &cN);

                    }
                     */

                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(yi=0;yi<height;yi++)
    {
        for(xi=0;xi<width;xi++)
            binary[yi*width+xi] &= 0x01;
    }
    *x = contourx;
    *y = contoury;
    *Nret = contourN;

    return answer;
}

static int walkcontour(unsigned char *binary, int width, int height, int x, int y, int dir, double **cx,
                 double **cy, int *Nret)
{
    int N = 0;
    int advance;
    int capacity = width + 3;
    double *xwalk, *ywalk;
    double *temp;
    unsigned char neighbours[9];
    int xi, yi;
    int mask;

    switch(dir)
    {
        case CNT_RIGHT: mask = CNT_TOPLEFT; break;
        case CNT_DOWN: mask = CNT_TOPRIGHT; break;
        case CNT_LEFT: mask = CNT_BOTTOMRIGHT; break;
        case CNT_UP: mask = CNT_BOTTOMLEFT; break;

    }
    mask = CNT_TOPLEFT;

    xwalk = malloc(capacity * sizeof(double));
    ywalk = malloc(capacity * sizeof(double));
    if(!xwalk || ! ywalk)
        goto out_of_memory;
    xi = x;
    yi = y;
    while(1)
    {
        get2x2(neighbours, binary, width, height, xi, yi, 0);
        advance = 0;
        while(advance == 0)
        {
            switch(dir)
            {
                case CNT_RIGHT:
                    if(neighbours[1] & 0x01)
                        dir = CNT_UP;
                    else
                        advance = 1;
                    break;
                case CNT_DOWN:
                    if(neighbours[3] & 0x01)
                        dir = CNT_RIGHT;
                    else
                        advance = 1;
                    break;
                case CNT_LEFT:
                    if(neighbours[2] & 0x01)
                        dir = CNT_DOWN;
                    else
                        advance = 1;
                    break;
                case CNT_UP:
                    if(neighbours[0] & 0x01)
                        dir = CNT_LEFT;
                    else
                        advance = 1;
                    break;

            }
        }

        xwalk[N] = xi;
        ywalk[N] = yi;
        N++;
        if(N >= capacity)
        {
            capacity += capacity/2;

            temp = realloc(xwalk, capacity * sizeof(double) );
            if(!temp)
                goto out_of_memory;
            xwalk = temp;

            temp = realloc(ywalk, capacity * sizeof(double) );
            if(!temp)
                goto out_of_memory;
            ywalk = temp;
        }
        advance = 0;

        if(yi < height && xi < width)
            binary[yi*width+xi] |= CNT_TOPLEFT;
        if(yi < height && xi > 0)
            binary[yi*width+xi-1] |= CNT_TOPRIGHT;
        if(yi > 0 && xi < width)
            binary[(yi-1)*width+xi] |= CNT_BOTTOMLEFT;
        if(xi > 0 && yi > 0)
                binary[(yi-1)*width+xi-1] |= CNT_BOTTOMRIGHT;

        switch(dir)
        {
            case CNT_RIGHT: xi++; break;
            case CNT_DOWN: yi++; break;
            case CNT_LEFT: xi--; break;
            case CNT_UP: yi--; break;
        }

        get2x2(neighbours, binary, width, height, xi, yi, 0);
        while(advance == 0)
        {
            switch(dir)
            {
                case CNT_RIGHT:
                    if( !(neighbours[3] & 0x01))
                        dir = CNT_DOWN;
                    else
                        advance = 1;
                    break;
                case CNT_DOWN:
                    if(!(neighbours[2] & 0x01))
                        dir = CNT_LEFT;
                    else
                        advance = 1;
                    break;
                case CNT_LEFT:
                    if(!(neighbours[0] & 0x01))
                        dir = CNT_UP;
                    else
                        advance = 1;
                    break;
                case CNT_UP:
                    if(!(neighbours[1] & 0x01))
                        dir = CNT_RIGHT;
                    else
                        advance = 1;
                    break;

            }
        }
        if(yi == y && xi == x && (binary[yi*width+xi] & mask) )
            break;

    }
    *cx = xwalk;
    *cy = ywalk;
    *Nret = N;
    return 0;
out_of_memory:
    free(xwalk);
    free(ywalk);
    *cx = 0;
    *cy  =0;
    *Nret  = 0;
    return -1;

}
```